# Different least square errors with armadillo functions

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, armadillo

Hello stackoverflow community,

I have troubles in understanding a least-square-error-problem in the c++ armadillo package.

I have a matrix A with many more rows than columns (5000 to 100 for example) so it is overdetermined.
I want to find x so that A*x=b gives me the least square error.

If i use the solve function of armadillo on my data like "x = Solve(A,b)" the error of "(A*x-b)^2" is sometimes way to high.
If on the other hand I solve for x with the analytical form by "x = (A^T * A)^-1 *A^T * b" the results are always right.
The results for x in both cases can differ by 10 magnitudes.
I had thought that armadillo would use this analytical form in the background if the system is overdetermined.
Now I would like to understand why these two methods give such different results.

I wanted to give a short example program, but i can't reproduce this behavior with a short program.
I thought about giving the Matrix here, but with 5000 times 100 it's also very big. I can deliver the values for which this happens though if needed.

So as a short background.
The matrix I get from my program is a numerically solved reaction of a nonlinear oscillator in which I put information inside by wiggeling a parameter of this system. 
Because the influence of this parameter on the system is small, the values of my different rows are very similar but never the same, otherwise armadillo should throw an error.
I'm still thinking that this is the problem, but the solve function never threw any error.

Another thing that confuses me is that in a short example program with a random matrix, the analytical form is waaay slower than the solve function.
But on my program, both are nearly identically fast.
I guess this has something to do with the numerical convergence of the pseudo inverse and the special case of my matrix, but for that i don't know enough about how armadillo works.

I hope someone can help me with that problem and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't know what Armadillo's solve does for non-square matrices. But, x = (A^T * A)^-1 *A^T * b solves x by performing a linear regression minimizing the squared differences. How do you calculate the "error of (x-b)^2"? Or is (x-b)^2 your measure of error?

Comment: Yes, i want to find x so that (A*x - b)^2 is minimized. Argh, sorry. I see that i forgot the A there. I also edited the post.

Comment: About the speed with the random matrix, you should provide some code to see what 's going on. Otherwise, it's impossible to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on how Armadillo solve's linear regressions? For example, if you have an over-determined system (A has more rows than columns), Matlab's \ operator performs a least-squares linear regression.

Comment: Why Armadillo throws an error if you have identical rows? I would understand that for square systems, not for over-determined ones.

Comment: I think you should post your question here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I think i figured the problem out and wanted to give some feedback for everybody who runs into the same problem.

The Armadillo solve function gives me the x that minimizes (A*x-b)^2.
I looked at the values of x and they are sometimes in the magnitude of 10^13.
This comes from the fact that the rows of my matrix only slightly change. (So nearly linear dependent but not exactly).
Because of that i was in the numerical precision of my doubles and as a result my error sometimes jumped around.

If i use the rearranged analytical formular (A^T * A)*x =  *A^T * b with the solve function this problem doesn't occur anymore because the fitted values of x are in the magnitude of 10^4. The least square error is a little bit higher but that is okay, as i want to avoid overfitting.

I now additionally added Tikhonov regularization by solving (A^T * A + lambda*Identity_Matrix)*x =  *A^T * b with the solve function of armadillo.
Now the weight vectors are in the order of around 1 and the error nearly doesn't change compared to the formular without regularization.